# How to find words or sentences around the found word?

Tags: python

How to find words next to the found word? I want to see the left word AND the right word of the found word x too.

I was able to extract the index of the found word in the sourcetext. But by doing sourcetext[sourceindex+1] it gives me just the letter of that word. It should give me the next word next to the found word. What am I doing wrong?

```
    sourcetext=browser.page_source
    searchword= ["hello","world","pretty","life"]
        
        
        for x in searchword:
      
            if x in sourcetext:
    
                sourceindex=sourcetext.index(x)
               
                print("FOUND!" + x + "  " + sourcetext[sourceindex+1])
                                   
            else:
                continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple solution and can be expanded to work with Selenium or Bs4.

```
sentence = "this is a six word sentence."
search = "six"

sentence = sentence.split(" ")

if search in sentence:
    my_index = sentence.index(search)
    word_before = my_index - 1
    word_after = my_index + 1

    print(sentence[word_before], search, sentence[word_after])
```

It works by splitting the original text into a list. The if statement takes a word or variable and checks if it is in the list, if it is it finds the index value of that word which is recorded in my_index. This can then be used to find the word before and after that word.

This can be a slow solution when larger texts are used.

Comment: Your approach is the one I wanted. You made a mistake. Please correct it. It's sentence.split() withtout " ". I just didn't know that you have to split the whole sentence first in order for this to work. Thanks!

Comment: This answer gives an error if the search word is the last word in the sentence

Answer (score 1):

**You can use try and except**

```py
sourcetext=browser.page_source
searchword= ["hello","world","pretty","life"]
        
        
for x in searchword:
      
    if x in sourcetext:
    
        sourceindex=sourcetext.index(x)
        next_word=""
        i=1
        while True:
            try:
                if sourcetext[sourceindex+len(x)+i] !=" ":
                    next_word+=sourcetext[sourceindex+len(x)+i]
                else:
                    break
                i+=1
            except IndexError:
                break
        print("FOUND!" + x + "  " + next_word)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to have the word to the left and right of the searchword. My approach here would be to use regex to find the words.

```
import re

for searchword in searchwords:
    match = re.search(r'(?:(\w*)\s)?{}(?:\s(\w*))?'.format(searchword), sourcetext)
    if match:
        print('{} is between {} and {}'.format(searchword, match.group(1), match.group(2)))
```

This solution should work quite well for long texts. For example, if there is no word on the left side, `group(1) = None` and you can query it easily.